# Using the all function with functions like str.islower()

Tags: python

```
if all(password.islower()) or (password.isalpha()) or (password.isalnum()):
    print("")
```

I am trying to make it so the if statment checks if all of the variable 'password' is lowercase but the `all` function is not working for me.

My problem is that there is an error message saying

```
TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

How can I use the `all` function and `any` function with another function like `.islower`? Also is the function `.isalnum` and `.isalpha` mean it check if all of the variable is a number or alphabetical?

Comment: Check the document...https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all

Answer (score 2):

For a password tester, you want to check if *any* of the characters are in a certain group:

```
any(c.islower() for c in password)
```

This is only going to be true if there is at least 1 lowercase character. You can combine these tests with `and` (don't use `all()` here, no point as there is no loop):

```
any(c.islower() for c in password) and any(c.isdigit() for c in password)
```

would only be true if there is at least one lowercase character and one digit in the password.

However, stringing these tests together gets unwieldy, fast. It is much easier to create a separate function, and spell out each password test:

```
def is_valid(password):
    if len(password) < 8:
        return False
    if not any(c in password for c in '!@%/()=?+.-'):
        return False
    if not any(c.isdigit() for c in password):
        return False
    if not any(c.islower() for c in password):
        return False
    if not any(c.isupper() for c in password):
        return False
    return True
```

and then just defer to that function when you need to see if your password is at least 8 characters long, uses both lowercase and uppercase letters, and contains at least 1 digit and 1 'special' character, for example:

```
if is_valid(password):
```

Using a dedicated function is far more maintainable.

If your password checker needs to be more flexible still, you use separate tests and collect them in a sequence. Only *then* is the `all()` function helpful, *all* tests need to pass:

```
def password_contains_lowercase(password):
    return any(c.is_lower() in password)

def password_contains_uppercase(password):
    return any(c.is_upper() in password)

def password_contains_digit(password):
    return any(c.is_digit() in password)

def password_min_length(length):
    def password_length_test(password):
        return len(password) >= min_length
    return password_length_test

# etc.

policies = {
    'mixed_case': (
        password_min_length(8),
        password_contains_lowercase,
        password_contains_uppercase
    ),
    'mixed_case_and_digits': (
        password_min_length(8),
        password_contains_lowercase,
        password_contains_uppercase,
        password_contains_digit
    ),
    # ...
}


def is_valid_password(policy, password):
    return all(test(password) for test in policies[policy])
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you explain what i do to check if all the characters in the password are lower case? I don't understand.

Comment: @ASAP: if *all* characters need to be lowercase, then just use `password.islower()`, no loops, no `all()` needed. The `str.islower()` method only returns true if *all* characters are lowercase. We just used it on strings with just *one* character in them when looping.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is that all expects an `iterable`,

> form docs
>   all(iterable) -> bool
>
> ```
> Return True if bool(x) is True for all values x in the iterable.
> If the iterable is empty, return True.
> ```

but the line

```
if all( password.islower()) or (password.isalpha() )
  #     ^--------will result in a `bool`----------^
  #      --------and NOT and iterable-------------
```

how you should use it:

```
if all( [password.islower(), password.isalpha(), password.isalnum()] ):
    print("")
```

Comment: in which case you'd just use `password.islower() and password.isalpha() and password.isalnum()`. But the latter test is always going to be true if `isalpha()` is true, and `isalpha()` is always true if `islower()` is true for the string. So the whole test is rather pointless as you can boil it down to `password.islower()`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters agreed, my whole point was to show him how he was using the `all` builtin in the wrong way, and the reason to that `bool` related error, as `all` expects an iterable. Also, i would mention again, using `and` will result in an error, you don't use logical operators inside arguments to `all`, so you're comment code won't run. `all`, as the name suggests tries to see if all passed in expressions return true on not, no case of `and` or `or`.

Comment: I didn't say you'd still use `all()` around all that. :-P